# Problem with Magento install on MAMP

Tags: installation, version, mamp

I've been trying to install Magento(2-2.4) on MAMP Pro on my macbook. I downloaded the code and am trying to install and I've gotten close but I can't figure out how to get past this screen:

[image]

There was no version set in the composer.json file so I tried "version": "2-2.4" and "version": "2.2.4" and I get the same result. Do I need to start over or am I overlooking something?

I apologize if this is a repost, I haven't been able to find anything and there's nothing in the error logs.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: hello @angler please try to install Magento using the command line I think this will help you, follow this reference https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/How-we-can-install-magento-2-2-0-via-command-line-comand/m-p/493468/highlight/true#M10598

Comment: I figured a command line install would be better, so it did install but now I just get the same screen with the version visibly set to "2.4.3", but still no button to start configuration.

Comment: You can setup using CLI only no button will appear.

Comment: Got it, so I got the message in the CLI that the installation was successful, but now I can't connect to the site. I've checked the error logs but there's nothing of any help. Any ideas on that?

Comment: As part of my ongoing oddities it's connecting now but  I get a general error screen and the error report is showing that the mysql connection is being refused.